# Tesseract OCR Problem with Digits on lang='deu'

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, digits

Today I faced an OCR problem I cannot explain at all.

Working with Terreract 5.0 and Python 3.9

I have a very clear digit number:

[image: picture]

When I make an OCR with standard setting, no problem, working fine.

In my application, the text forms are 99% german language, so I use

```
text=pytesseract.image_to_string(im,lang='deu')
```

I got the language set from
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/main/deu.traineddata
and it seems to work fine on most non-digits elements.

It's working fine, but on some very very clear numbers, tesseract gets some very crazy results. On the attached image, the OCR result is 7318587**9**, which is very strange...

I already tried to use a whitelist,
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, config='-c tessedit_char_whitelist=-0123456789')
but the result is the same

Here is another Number:

[image: picture]

When I run it with the standard configuration, the result is
**19**215056
When I switch to German charset, it becomes even crazier:
**719**2153056

Does anyone have an idea how to handle it?
Is there another way to use standard language and add some special characters like 'ä,ß' as a workaround?
Thanks for any hints

EDIT:

I reduced the pictures the 30% and OCR works perfectly, so the problem might be on detecting big chars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading [tesseract documentation](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/main/ImproveQuality.md#rescaling) can save a lot of headache.

Comment: You are absoulty right, but this does not give an answer to y problem.
The two example are an extract from a pdf with only 75 dpi! The letters are unusual big. 
As Adam wrote, the size in relation to the image blob seems to be important.

Comment: Rescaling part of doc links analyzes for optimum letter size.

Comment: Thanks user898678, 
indeed only for a letter height of ~20 px there are optimal results.

Answer (score 0):

Most definitely font size is causing this problems.
I did run it through my tesseract app and with big image the confidence level is at 81%, with smaller one it's up to 96%.
Similar issue here: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/3480

[image]

[image]

Comment: If true:  new thought, machine also kind of work like eyes as on zooming out we can read things more clearly

Comment: As  user898678 mentioned in his link to tesseract documentation, only letter height of ~20px give very good results